# Find count of consecutive values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the count of consecutive values in order to change it to another value. Example :

```
A
A
B
A
B
B
B
B
A
```

If there are consecutive values (AA, AAA, AAAA.. or BB, BBB, BBBB...) then replace the second and corresponding values with C

I tried the following code:

```
Dim values As Integer
values = Range().Rows.Count

For i = 1 To values
    If Range().Cells(i, 1) = Range().Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
        Range().Cells(i + 1, 1) = “C”
    End If
Next i
```

However this only takes into account 2 consecutive values and not more than 2.. how do I fix my code?

Appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: Run your loop **backwards**.  That is from the bottom upwards, rather than top down.

Comment: @FaneDuru, I deleted my comment as it was essentially the same comment as Gary's student's. I have posted a code below inline with the same comment.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij: I deleted my comment, too... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the next code, please. In your code, after first replace, the condition does not matches, anymore. The code assumes that the column to be processed is "A:A":

```
Sub removeConsecRowsValue()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, values As Long, i As Long, j As Long
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
   values = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'supposing that the column to be processed is A:A
    For i = 1 To values
        If sh.Range("A" & i).value = sh.Range("A" & i + 1).value Then
            Dim rng As Range
            For j = i + 1 To i + 1000
                If sh.Range("A" & j).value = sh.Range("A" & i).value Then
                    If rng Is Nothing Then
                       Set rng = sh.Range("A" & j)
                    Else
                       Set rng = Union(rng, sh.Range("A" & j))
                    End If
                Else
                    rng.Replace sh.Range("A" & i).value, "C"
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Replace Consecutive

- Copy the complete code into a standard module (e.g. `Module1`).
- Run only the `Sub`.
- The `Function` is called by the `Sub`.
- Adjust the **constants** in the `Sub`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConsecutiveExample()

    Const rngAddress As String = "A1:A20"
    Const Criteria As Variant = "C"

    Dim rng As Range:Set rng = Range(rngAddress)
    Dim Target As Variant:Target = replaceConsecutive(rng, Criteria)

    If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then rng.Value = Target

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Replaces each next consecutive value in a one-column range
'               with a specified criteria and returns a 2D one-based one-column
'               array containing the modified values.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function replaceConsecutive(SourceRange As Range, ByVal Criteria As Variant, _
  Optional ByVal AnyColumn As Long = 1) As Variant

    Dim Source As Variant: Source = SourceRange.Columns(AnyColumn).Value
    If Not IsArray(Source) Then Exit Function

    Dim Target As Variant: Target = Source
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To UBound(Source)
        If Source(i, 1) = Source(i - 1, 1) Then Target(i, 1) = Criteria
    Next i
    Erase Source

    replaceConsecutive = Target

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just reverse the loop and test the conditions as @Gary's student has suggested. See below code.

```
Dim lngLastRow As Long, i As Long
lngLastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = lngLastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i - 1).Value Then Range("A" & i).Value = "C"
Next i
```